# Set zoom level to 100% in Selenium WebDriver when default is not 100

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I'm running into an issue with Selenium WebDriver in Java, where I can't set the IE browser zoom level to 100% when the user has a different default value. Ctrl + 0 does not work since this sets the zoom to the default. I've tried setting zoom through a JavascriptExecutor, as seen in other posts as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, Selenium doesn't communicates well with `Internet Explorer` until and unless `Zoom Level` is set to `100%`. Any specific business case not to set `Zoom Level` to `100%`? Thanks

Comment: I'm using Selenium for a web browser automation application, and running into issues when certain test users have default zoom levels other than 100%, so I need to change it in the code.

Comment: Can you share the specific business case (Testcase) where users have to set zoom levels other than 100%? Thanks

Comment: Certain machines that may run my application simply have the zoom level at higher than 100%. I'd rather not force them to change this before using it. There is no specific business case.

Comment: I would recommend, before you start your `Automated Test Execution` give yourself time to setup & configure the `Test Environment` first. Successful `Test Execution Result` depends a lot on it. For your reference, [**`here is the link`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) to the guide for IE settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try ignoring the zoom level all together.

`DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);`

You can see others with the zoom issue here: [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034969/internetexplorerdriver-zoom-level-error)

Comment: see my comments above.

Comment: This does not work, as when the zoom level is, say 125%, certain elements cannot be identified. Ignoring the zoom setting allows the browser to open, but the driver can't click on many things.

Comment: @jonlip That was my concern.

Answer (score 1):

From what I googled, you can set the default zoom using the registry. I haven't tried this myself but you should be able to grab the user's default setting, change it to 100% (if it's not there already), do your test, and then restore their default setting.

I haven't tried this myself but it looks pretty straightforward.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USERS\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom
```

Set ZoomFactor to 1000x the factor you want, e.g. 125% is 125000

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2689447/how-to-set-the-zoom-level-in-internet-explorer-9

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can tweak the calculation which returns the current zoom level, I may be wrong at that

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Automation Projects\\Selenium Server\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('Https://www.google.com')

zoom_level = driver.execute_script('return (window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth)')
if zoom_level > 1:
    driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='90%';")
```

Comment: This gave me some hope, but didn't work. The page zoom is getting changed, But the browser zoom in browser settings, is still showing the same number..  and selenium still fails to identify elements. If i put browse zoom as 100 and run  document.body.style.zoom='10%'  only, then  it will make the page tiny, still the code will work. because the browse zoom is 100% even now.  I think selenium is not bothered about this document zoom.

Answer (score 1):

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='100%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code, It is working code

```
InternetExplorerOptions capabilities= new InternetExplorerOptions();
            capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constant.drivers + "\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: This only ignores the zoom check, Browser will open but wont identify any element